# Rain effect with SFML

Tags: c++, beginner, animation, sfml

I decided to write a rain effect to learn how to use SFML, and I would like to get some review on my code: i want to know how you would have write the program, and how to improve my code. This program accepts one parameter to change the wind direction.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Graphics.hpp"

void help() noexcept
{
    std::cerr << "Param:" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Wind Direction:       none:0, left:1, right:2" << std::endl;
}

bool isNumber(const std::string& s) noexcept
{
    return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return
        !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) noexcept
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        help();
        return -1;
    }

    std::string arg1 = argv[1];
    if(!isNumber(arg1) || arg1.size() > 1 || (std::stoi(arg1) < 0 ||
        std::stoi(arg1) > 2))
    {
        std::cerr << "The parameter must be a number between 0 and 2" <<
            std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    Graphics graphics(std::stoi(arg1));
    graphics.run();

    return 0;
}
```

WaterDroplet.hpp

```
#ifndef DEF_WATER_DROPLET_HPP
#define DEF_WATER_DROPLET_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include "Config.hpp"

//min size: Vector2f(15, 1), max size: sf::Vector2f(35, 3)
//rotation: depends of the wind direction, no: 90, left: 135, right: 45
class WaterDroplet
{
public:
    WaterDroplet(unsigned short windDirection);

    ~WaterDroplet();

    unsigned short getRotation() const;

    sf::Vector2f getSize() const;

    sf::Vector2f getPosition() const;

private:
    unsigned short rotation_;
    sf::Vector2f size_;
    sf::Vector2f position_;
};

#endif //DEF_WATER_DROPLET_HPP
```

WaterDroplet.cpp

```
#include "WaterDroplet.hpp"

WaterDroplet::WaterDroplet(unsigned short windDirection)
{
    unsigned int seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
        .count();
    std::default_random_engine eng(seed);
    if(windDirection == static_cast<short>(Config::WIND_DIRECTION_NO))
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distPositionX(10,
            static_cast<int>(Config::WINDOW_X));
        position_.y = 0;
        position_.x = distPositionX(eng);
        rotation_ = 90;
    }
    else if(windDirection == static_cast<short>
        (Config::WIND_DIRECTION_LEFT))
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distPositionX(0,
            static_cast<int>(Config::WINDOW_X));
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distPositionY(0,
            static_cast<int>(Config::WINDOW_Y));
        position_.x = distPositionX(eng);
        position_.y = distPositionY(eng);
        rotation_ = 135;
    }
    else
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distPositionX(0,
            static_cast<int>(Config::WINDOW_X));
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distPositionY(0,
            static_cast<int>(Config::WINDOW_Y));
        position_.x = distPositionX(eng);
        position_.y = distPositionY(eng);
        rotation_ = 45;
    }

    std::uniform_int_distribution<short> distSizeX(15, 35);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned short> distSizeY(1, 3);
    size_.x = distSizeX(eng);
    size_.y = distSizeY(eng);
}

WaterDroplet::~WaterDroplet()
{

}

unsigned short WaterDroplet::getRotation() const
{
    return rotation_;
}

sf::Vector2f WaterDroplet::getSize() const
{
    return size_;
}

sf::Vector2f WaterDroplet::getPosition() const
{
    return position_;
}
```

Graphics.hpp

```
#ifndef DEF_GRAPHICS_HPP
#define DEF_GRAPHICS_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "WaterDroplet.hpp"
#include "Config.hpp"

class Graphics
{
public:
    Graphics(unsigned short windDirection);

    ~Graphics();

    void run() noexcept;

private:
    void processEvents() noexcept;

    void update() noexcept;

    void render() noexcept;

    float velocity_ { 0.5 };
    unsigned short windDirection_;
    sf::RenderWindow window_;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::RectangleShape>> rectangleShapes_;
    sf::Clock clock_;
    sf::Clock movementWaterDropletClock_;
};

#endif //DEF_GRAPHICS_HPP
```

Graphics.cpp

```
#include "Graphics.hpp"

Graphics::Graphics(unsigned short windDirection) : windDirection_(windDirection)
    , window_(sf::VideoMode(static_cast<int>(Config::WINDOW_X), static_cast
        <int>(Config::WINDOW_Y)), "Rain")
{

}

Graphics::~Graphics()
{

}

void Graphics::run() noexcept
{
    while(window_.isOpen())
    {
        processEvents();
        update();
        render();
    }
}

void Graphics::processEvents() noexcept
{
    sf::Event event;
    while(window_.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window_.close();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Graphics::update() noexcept
{
    if(clock_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() > 10)
    {
        WaterDroplet waterDroplet(windDirection_);
        std::unique_ptr<sf::RectangleShape> rectangleShape =
            std::make_unique<sf::RectangleShape>
            (waterDroplet.getSize());
        rectangleShape->setPosition(waterDroplet.getPosition());
        rectangleShape->setRotation(waterDroplet.getRotation());
        rectangleShape->setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 65, 128));
        rectangleShapes_.push_back(std::move(rectangleShape));
        clock_.restart();
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < rectangleShapes_.size(); ++i)
    {
        movementWaterDropletClock_.restart();
        sf::Time time = movementWaterDropletClock_.getElapsedTime();
        float elapsedTime = time.asSeconds();

        if(windDirection_ == static_cast<unsigned short>
            (Config::WIND_DIRECTION_NO))
                rectangleShapes_[i]->move(0, velocity_ + elapsedTime);
        else if(windDirection_ == static_cast<unsigned short>
            (Config::WIND_DIRECTION_LEFT))
            rectangleShapes_[i]->move(-velocity_ - elapsedTime,
                velocity_ + elapsedTime);
        else
            rectangleShapes_[i]->move(velocity_ + elapsedTime, velocity_
                + elapsedTime);

        if(rectangleShapes_[i]->getPosition().y > static_cast<int>
            (Config::WINDOW_Y) + 10)
            rectangleShapes_.erase(rectangleShapes_.begin() + i);
    }
}

void Graphics::render() noexcept
{
    window_.clear();
    for(const auto& rectangleShape: rectangleShapes_)
        window_.draw(*rectangleShape);
    window_.display();
}
```

Config.hpp

```
#ifndef DEF_CONFIG_HPP
#define DEF_CONFIG_HPP

enum class Config
{
    WINDOW_X                    = 800,
    WINDOW_Y                    = 800,
    WIND_DIRECTION_NO           = 0,
    WIND_DIRECTION_LEFT         = 1,
    WIND_DIRECTION_RIGHT        = 2
};

#endif //DEF_CONFIG_HPP
```

Answer (score 3):

This is really straightforward and easy to understand. Nice work! I have a few suggestions.

## Use The Right Type

It's a little odd that you used an `enum` for the `Config` type. Usually an enumeration is a set of options that are all related. But `WINDOW_X` and `WINDOW_Y` are completely unrelated to `WIND_DIRECTION`. I would suggest that `WINDOW_X` and `WINDOW_Y` should be named constants. I would do this:

```
const sf::Vector2i kWindowSize(800, 800);
enum class WindDirection
{
    WINDOW_DIRECTION_NO    = 0,
    WINDOW_DIRECTION_LEFT  = 1,
    WINDOW_DIRECTION_RIGHT = 2
};
```

If you want to put it in a namespace, that would be reasonable, too. Although, looking at the numerous `static_cast<int>`s you have, it seems like it would be easier to just make them named constants with the correct type, as well. (And I note that sometimes you cast them to `int`, sometimes `short`, and sometimes `unsigned short`. That indicates that something isn't the right type.)

## Naming

For the most part your naming is really good. I would change `Graphics` to `Renderer`, as `Graphics` is a very generic term. These days it pretty much means anything on the screen. The name `Renderer` tells you what the object actually does.

## Simplify

I think the code in the `for` loop in `Graphics::update()` could be made simpler. I would call `rectangleShapes_[i]->move` on it only once. Something like this:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < rectangleShapes_.size(); ++i)
{
    movementWaterDropletClock_.restart();
    sf::Time time = movementWaterDropletClock_.getElapsedTime();
    float elapsedTime = time.asSeconds();

    float xOffset = 0;
    float yOffset = velocity_ + elapsedTime;
    if (windDirection_ == Config::WIND_DIRECTION_LEFT)
    {
        xOffset = -velocity_ - elapsedTime;
    }
    else if (windowDirection_ == Config::WIND_DIRECTION_RIGHT)
    {
        xOffset = velocity_ + elapsedTime;
    }
    rectangleShapes_[i]->move(xOffset, yOffset);

    if(rectangleShapes_[i]->getPosition().y > Config::kWindowSize.y + 10)
    {
        rectangleShapes_.erase(rectangleShapes_.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Yes, I could have cast the window dimensions to unsigned int, and the wind directions to unsigned short, but I didn't know that I could to make an enum with a well-defined type.